# Roles.Enabled is true even if roleManger.enabled is set to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a simple web site with one aspx page (`Test.aspx`) showing `Roles.Enabled` value which is set to false in `Web.config` (attribute `roleManager@enabled`).

**Test.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%= Roles.Enabled %>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <roleManager enabled="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This outputs:

> **False**

Which is expected.

However, when I add another file (a razor page), e.g. `Test.cshtml` with no content inside (0 B), the aspx page suddenly outputs:

> **True**

The output is not changed even if I remove the razor page from the site. I have to recycle the application pool and then it again outputs `False` (the expected result).

It seems that the *MVC* module / handler factory changes the values for some unknown reason.

How can I tell the *MVC* runtime not to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The key which could turn on the simple membership is the AppSetting `enableSimpleMembership` (default is `true`?).

Apparently, when a MVC project starts, a routine checks if this setting is set to `false`. If not the [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) is applied -or ASP.NET try to- somehow [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213093/what-would-be-equivalent-web-config-configuration-for-enablesimplemembership).

To disable this behavior, set it to `false`.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

I found this remark in the [`PreApplicationStartCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.preapplicationstartcode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) of WebMatrix. I guess there is a similar behavior for most MVC versions.

> To use the SimpleMembershipProvider and WebSecurity classes for an
>   ASP.NET Web Pages website, set **enableSimpleMembership** to true in the
>   appSetting section of the Web.config file. (Alternatively, leave
>   **enableSimpleMembership** out of the Web.config file, because
>   **enableSimpleMembership** defaults to true.) When simple membership is
>   enabled, SimpleMembershipProvider replaces SqlMembershipProvider, but
>   is not invoked until it is initialized by a call to the
>   InitializeDatabaseConnection() method.

Answer (score 0):

try setting this key. basically simplemembership is being turned on which is why roles are enabled