# What would be equivalent web.config configuration for "enableSimpleMembership"="true:

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, roleprovider, simplemembership

What would be equivalent configuration of Membership and Role providers in Web.Config for:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up SimpleMembership in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170726/setting-up-simplemembership-in-mvc4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalent configuration of web.config would be:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" /><!-- false is default if key is not present -->
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I'm getting Unrecognized configuration section roleManager with this in my app.config for tests.

Comment: Indeed. I edited answer. membership and roleManager under <system.web> node.

Comment: yes, works this way. However I've been having assembly errors until I've added assembly name like this: ```type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"```