# Using SimpleMembership in a Worker Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm running a MVC4 website on windows azure. I've created a worker role to perform scheduled tasks. One of these tasks requires deleting user who have not confirmed their registration for a long time. I need to use SimpleMembershipProvider in my worker but I can't configure it. I get exceptions roleManager feature is not enabled. I've tried adding the following to my app.config (found somewhere on the internet, can't find any documentation for it):

`<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="WebConfigRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="WebConfigRoleProvider" type="WebConfigRoleProvider.Core.WebConfigRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>`

and now I get errors about WebConfigRoleProvider missing from some assembly.

Please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be equivalent web.config configuration for "enableSimpleMembership"="true:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213093/what-would-be-equivalent-web-config-configuration-for-enablesimplemembership)