# Simple Membership Provider - Azure WebJob

Tags: azure-webjobs

I've set up an Azure WebJob for a process that can send out a lot of invites to new users via a single request. I'm using SimpleMembership but I'm getting the following error

`The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.`

I've looked at this question/answer [Mvc Runtime error - The Role Manager feature has not been enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329159/mvc-runtime-error-the-role-manager-feature-has-not-been-enabled)

Which I think will solve the problem I'm having, but I'm unsure where I can put this in the `app.config` (WebJobs don't have a `web.config`)

I've also tried this [What would be equivalent web.config configuration for "enableSimpleMembership"="true:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213093/what-would-be-equivalent-web-config-configuration-for-enablesimplemembership) but thats not helping.

I need to know where to include the following sections in the `app.config`

```
   <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that in the `app.config` you actually include a `<system.web>` section...

```
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```